# How could I make the raw command run just as the npm alias does?

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, cypress, package.json

How could I make the raw command run just as the npm alias does?

I have the following inside my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "cypress:test": "cypress-ntlm run --config-file tests/cypress-config.json"
  }
```

And the command `npm run cypress:test` executes just fine.

But if I try to run the raw command:

```
cypress-ntlm run --config-file tests/cypress-config.json
```

, then I am getting the error: `bash: cypress-ntlm: command not found`.

I want to be able to run raw command as well as the npm aliased command.

Does the npm alias has some dependencies specific only for the alias? E.g. the `cypress-ntlm` in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your command prefixed by `npx` or `npm exec`. I'm not an npm expert by any means, but in my mind I've always equated `npm run {script}` as being almost equivalent to `npx {script contents}`. `cypress-ntlm` suggests in their docs running `npx cypress-ntlm {options}`.